# Is it fine if I put a conditional if else statement on my google analytics script?

Tags: if-statement, google-analytics

I tested my tracking code via console and it's already working but I haven't tested it on live server. I just want to ask if this would work?

Here's my sample GA tracking code:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $url = $(location).attr('href');

        if ($url.indexOf('https://test.com/') > -1) {
            alert('TEST first');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-6', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        } else if ($url.indexOf('https://test2.com/') > -1) {
            alert('TEST second');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-7', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        } else if ($url.indexOf('https://test3.com/') > -1) {
            alert('TEST third');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-8', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        } else {
            alert('TEST fourth');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        }
    });


</script>
```

Will update once it worked.

Comment: Sure, why not. However you are delaying the tracking until after the DOM has loaded. This might give some visitors time to abandon their visit before the tracking call went out, so you would not count those visits. Probably no big deal, but you can just as well drop the DOM ready call and simply include this in your page header.

Comment: Thank you Eike! Sure, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed these codes and it's working perfectly fine. The thing is, Google Tag Assistant detects all of the other Analytics ID though it only records what has been identified on the if else statement.

I updated my code to javascript instead of using jQuery. Here's my updated code:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.indexOf('https://test.com/') > -1) {
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-6', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    } else if (url.indexOf('https://test2.com/') > -1) {
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-7', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    } else if (url.indexOf('https://test3.com/') > -1) {
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-8', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    } else {
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Google Tag Manager for this purpose because it's more scalable and you don't need to write any piece of code at all to get the same result. It's all done by triggers configuration.

Comment: Hi Dmitry! Thank you. I would want to use GTM but the site is already established so it's hard for me to configure everything but I would recommend everyone to do it like this.

Comment: This doesn't sound much like an answer to the OP question. Comments should go in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you only need to conditionally change the **property ID**, you don't have to condition the whole thing, including those that are constant, e.g. `ga('send', 'pageview')`:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    var url = window.location.href;
    var propertyID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3'; // Default

    if (url.indexOf('https://test.com/') > -1) {
        propertyID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-6';

    } else if (url.indexOf('https://test2.com/') > -1) {
        propertyID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-7';

    } else if (url.indexOf('https://test3.com/') > -1) {
        propertyID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-8';
    };

    ga('create', propertyID, 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```